# Построение прямой, которая будет указывать на позицию чекпоинта

Tags: c#

Появилась такая проблема:

Нужно на машине доехать до определённого чекпоинта. Есть координаты машины и чекпоинта.

Объяснение в картинке:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно что-то типа:

```
if (car_position > 90(градусов){

Turn_LefT();

}

if (car_position < 90(градусов){

Turn_Right();

}

if (car_position == 90(градусов){

Just_Ride_Forward();

}
```

Заранее спасибо.